# run graphlab from Spyder

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, spyder, graphlab

I can run my python file with imported functionalities from GraphLab from the Terminal (first use the `source activate gl-env` and then run the file). So the file and installations are alright in that sense.

However, I can't figure out how to run the file directly in Spyder IDE. I only get `ImportError: No module named 'graphlab'`. The Spyder runs with python3.5 and I've tried to change to 2.7 as the GraphLap seems to, but it doesn't work either (I redirected to the same python2.7 'scientific_startup.py' used in GraphLab lib ).

I wonder if anyone knows how to run the file directly from Spyder??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following method will solve this:

Open `Spyder --> tools --> preferences --> python interpreter` --> change from default to custom and select the python executable under gl-env environment. 
Restart spyder. It will work.